# Making box-shadow start more from the center

Tags: css

So I have this decorative frame image which should have a glow effect when hovered.
If I apply box-shadow, the glow doesn't follow the frame (it still forms a square). My thoughts for this problem is to make the box-shadow start more from the center.
Is there any way I can do this? Or should I try a different approach?

```
<div class="card">
   <img src="Frame.png">
</div>
```

```
.card {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: calc(0px + 0.75vw);
  float:left;
  border-radius:5px;
  display:table;
  margin: 3vw 5vw;
  position:relative;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.card:hover{
  transform: scale(1.02);
  box-shadow: 0 12px 100px 0 rgba(208, 200, 179, 0.9), 0 5px 70px 0 rgba(62, 100, 86, 1);
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
```

*not the full code

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `inset`?  possibly what you are looking for `box-shadow: 0 12px 100px 0 inset rgba(208, 200, 179, 0.9), 0 5px 70px 0 inset rgba(62, 100, 86, 1);`

Comment: No, inset would result in a glow to the inside. I'm planning to have an outside glow, but move the glow source not from the image border, but from the center of the image